# Image Map Programing in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, imagemap

I Want to write a Windows Application that uses an **Image of map** and when a user clicks on a location in the **Image**,the application shows some information about the location which are saved in a  a database file.

how can i write codes for map?
what component can i use?
what library can i use?
any information can help me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to start simply:

1. Find an image of the map.
2. Put it on your form.
3. Handle the `OnMouseUp` event of the image, use the X and Y values from the `MouseEventArgs` so you know where the user clicked, then translate it to something meaningful, and lookup the relevant information in the database.

You'll have to add a little more detail to your question to get a more detailed answer.